# how can i resolve a watcom linker error related to name mangling, on debian linux?

Tags: c, linux, linker

I'm using the Open Watcom 1.9 compiler on Debian linux,

and I'm trying to create an X11 window, but the compilation happens normally until the linker complains.

I suspect wpp386 is doing this, but I'm not sure.

> ```
>   __________(MAIN.CPP)__________________________________________
> /____________________________________________________________\
> main.cpp: 41 lines, included 6718, no warnings, no errors
> ________________________________________________________________
> \____________________________________________________________/
>
>
>
>
>   __________(Linker)________________________________________
> /__________________________________________________________\
> Error! E2028: XOpenDisplay_ is an undefined reference
> Error! E2028: XCreateSimpleWindow_ is an undefined reference
> Error! E2028: XSelectInput_ is an undefined reference
> Error! E2028: XMapWindow_ is an undefined reference
> Error! E2028: XNextEvent_ is an undefined reference
> Error! E2028: XCloseDisplay_ is an undefined reference
> Error! E2044: exported symbol XOpenDisplay_ not found
> Error! E2044: exported symbol XCreateSimpleWindow_ not found
> Error! E2044: exported symbol XSelectInput_ not found
> Error! E2044: exported symbol XMapWindow_ not found
> Error! E2044: exported symbol XNextEvent_ not found
> Error! E2044: exported symbol XCloseDisplay_ not found
> ________________________________________________________________
> \__________________________________________________________/
> ```

and shell  code is .

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>  
>
> echo "  __________(MAIN.CPP)__________________________________________"
> echo "/____________________________________________________________\\"
>   wpp386 -6r "main.cpp" -fp6 -Fo="main"  \
>   2>&1 | grep -v "Open Watcom\|Portions\|See"
> echo "________________________________________________________________"
> echo "\\____________________________________________________________/"
> echo ""
> echo ""
> echo ""
> echo ""
> echo "  __________(Linker)________________________________________"
> echo "/__________________________________________________________\\"
>   wlink option quiet name opengl_test file *.o \
>   library /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a \
>   2>&1 | grep -v "Open Watcom\|Portions\|See"
> echo "________________________________________________________________"
> echo "\\__________________________________________________________/"
> echo "_"
>
> rm -f *.o
>
>
>
> read -p "Press Enter to continue..."
> ```

Comment: Isn't wpp386 the 32-bit compiler? (I do not know the name of the 64-bit compiler in the "v2" fork, but I guess it has a different name to the 32-bit compiler?) Anyway, you cannot link 32-bit compiled code to 64-bit libraries such as /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a.

Comment: If wpp386 is producing 32-bit code, perhaps you could link to /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.a instead? That is installed as part of the `libx11-dev:i386` Debian package.

Comment: I already installed libx11-dev:i386 , and it was in this directory /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ , but even so it continues to keep errors, I don't know why it puts an underscore at the end of the function, the libX11 I was using it was also x32 , even wlib opened the library and showed data about libX11.a , it seems that this is more salty

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the `-bt=linux` option to the `wpp386` compiler and the `runtime linux` directive to `wlink`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Error! E2044: exported symbol XOpenDisplay_ not found`

Your compiler mangles global function names (appends `_` to them). That is *not* a reasonable thing to do (but see below), and if you can't find a flag which stops it from doing that, then your options are limited:

1. You could rebuilt all the libraries you depend on using the same `wpp386` (good luck with that!) or
2. You could use `objcopy --redefine-sym` to update all of your object files to use `XOpenDisplay` instead of `XOpenDisplay_` etc.

For option 2: beware -- it's possible that `wpp386` is using a non-standard calling convention. *If so*, using mangled name *is* actually reasonable, and only option 1 would work (because in that case code compiled with `wpp386` is *ABI-incompatible* with standard libraries).

P.S. [This documentation](http://users.pja.edu.pl/%7Ejms/qnx/help/watcom/compiler-tools/cpopts.html) says

> The default naming convention for all global functions is such that an underscore character (_) is suffixed to the symbol name.

but doesn't say how to get rid of it.

Comment: oh , thanks for the documentation , es was just looking through the openwatcom.org documentation , the solution was to add -6s and not -6r


The naming convention for all global functions and variables is modified such that no underscore characters (_) are prefixed or suffixed to the symbol name.